# error using boolean indexing with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, boolean

I have a column `"APNT_NA_ACTN"` that provides the type of coding used to hire employees:

```
115, 515, 100, 786, 101, etc...
```

I have aliased my set of data as names, therefore `names[:3]` provides three rows of the entire set.

I have the ability to filter one type of code:

```
names[names['APNT_NA_ACTN'] == 115]
names
```

but, I want to filter only: 115 and 515 from this column.  I've tried the following

```
temp = names[(names['APNT_NA_ACTN'] == 115) & (names['APNT_NA_ACTN'] == 515)]
temp
```

and I have also tried:

```
temp = names.query('[100,515] in 'APNT_NA_ACTN')
```

can anyone offer assistance?

thanks

so in all both suggestions below worked for me:

1)  temp = names[names['APNT_NA_ACTN'].isin([115,515])]

2)  hiring_code = names['APNT_NA_ACTN']
temp = names[(hiring_code == 115) | (hiring_code == 515)]
temp[['NM_EMP_LST','NAT_ACTN_2_3','ACTN_YMD','ORG_LEV2','ORG_LEV3','APNT_NA_ACTN','APNT_YMD','SCD_LV_YMD','SSNO','year']]

Comment: An alternative is `names['APNT_NA_ACTN'].isin([115,515)]`

Comment: I like this concept, however I receive the error: isin() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)  I entered the code like this:  names['APNT_NA_ACTN'].isin([115,515)] names

Comment: Sorry typo error, try this: `names['APNT_NA_ACTN'].isin([115,515])]`

Comment: yes, this totally worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin):

```
names['APNT_NA_ACTN'].isin([115,515])]
```

You can pass a list or a Series to the method

Answer (score 1):

Use `|` (logical-or) instead of `&` (logical-and):

```
hiring_code = names['APNT_NA_ACTN']
temp = names[(hiring_code == 115) | (hiring_code == 515)]
```

Comment: this seemed to provide what I needed.  totally grateful all input!